# What languages and tools does amazon use to build their api?

Tags: api, amazon-web-services

I know amazon has several api's but I was wondering what language and tools does amazon use to build their api, is it java and soap?  Im not sure if all the api's are created the same way, but if not then how is the one for mobile apps created?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon are notoriously secretive about the internals of their systems so I don't think you'll find a satisfactory answer.

The AWS APIs, as far as I know, use Java internally & they use plenty of C++ to run their shopping website